# Resize the Careers web site

Tags: bug, status-declined, jobs, user-interface

With the the latest changes in Careers/Jobs site I don't see:
* job position
* company
* location

Every piece of info is shortened. Everything is put in this one tiny column in the center of the monitor.

Despite, in previous version, info was laid out using entire screen (which is a good thing, after all people buy 22" monitors for using that size).

So please, either use entire screen for listing or provide way for EASY resize the column with job offers.